# Heroku: download and restore database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

My heroku rails app has following database settings for production

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

As you can see there is no password in the database. I downloaded the database with the commands

```
heroku pg:backups:capture    
heroku pg:backups:download
```

Now I want to restore the database, which command should I run to restore the database?

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me

```
pg_restore -d myapp_development -U rails_dev -C latest.dump
```

Here, my local development database `myapp_development`, local database username `rails_dev`  and `latest.dump` is the backup database file downloaded from server. Command above ask for a password which should be the password associated with user rails_dev.